# Where to submit your dissatisfaction, critique or review of a SE forum?

Tags: discussion, contact

Meta of the forum is same as main. I will of course not name the site(s). But where to submit your opinion regarding that site? It seems as much as Jeff Atwood's vision was to help a community grow and succeed one cannot often see ganging up, bullying and coercion by multi-downvoting et al.

As much as I oppose the "badge" of peer pressure to delete a question, that got more than 3 downvotes, it just says that the person does not have a confidence in his beliefs, opinions, or viewpoint to begin with if he is coerced by peers to delete it. That was an example. But coming to my main point, is this the place to discuss the abuse of Atwood's original vision?

Comment: As much as you probably hate to do it, specific examples would help. Do you have a problem with the system itself, or some of its users? This sounds more like a rant than a real question. As much as you seem to stand for your beliefs, you also seem to be saying that it's "not OK" to downvote (i.e. let other users have an opinion). I rarely (basically never) seen any issues like this, what exactly are you actually complaining about?

Comment: @Madmartigan But I am not cognizant of the process. I don't have problem with the system but group of users. It seems that there is an 'inner circle' of moderators and friends who point out certain links in chats. That is fine. But my concern was not downvote, which is of course the whole point of a democratic forum, but the tone. Politeness - does not mean with smileys or redundant 'thanks'- builds a better community in my opinion. After all I signed up to get help not to be in a trial on court.

Comment: We aren't a "forum", btw.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing this is your question that caused the trouble

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93122/an-informal-sketch-of-set-theoretic-proof-of-prime-numbers-infinitude

Sounds like your communication of your question got across poorly. You don't have to delete the question if you don't want to do it. That's your choice, never let someone force you to delete.

On another note,

Math.SE has its own sub-vision inside of the SE (making the internet better) vision. And for you to see that, requires you to get your points across as clear as possible in their academic setting. Math.SE is a Q&A first but academic site second.

I think you should have started at math.se meta or chatroom to understand their policies on how their site works.

Comment: Yes. It did. I know a new user might take a while to get _accepted_ but when I entered chat it seemed everyone knows each other and tend to be a bit cold at newcomers. But I got my answer to this question already. :)

Answer (score 4):

> it just says that the person does not have a confidence in his beliefs, opinions, or viewpoint to begin with if he is coerced by peers to delete it.

Coerced or... *convinced?*

Yeah, the badge name is a bit tongue in cheek. Ideally, if you posted an incorrect answer, you'd see the error - either upon your own review, in response to comments, or after viewing other answers - and either correct or remove the post. If instead you find others merely unaccepting of an answer you know to be true, then instead of deletion perhaps a better course of action would be to revise it and attempt to find a better way to communicate your ideas to those who've at first glance rejected them.

Anyway... In regard to your primary question: there's a **contact us** link at the bottom of every page that reveals the email of the site administrators. Use this for issues you *cannot* bring up on meta for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm guessing that the tongue in cheek was lost in translation...

Comment: Also, the SE network is not a place to post **beliefs** - we try to post facts backed up by evidence.

Answer (score 4):

You give an example:

> As much as I oppose the "badge" of peer pressure to delete a question, that got more than 3 downvotes, it just says that the person does not have a confidence in his beliefs, opinions, or viewpoint to begin with if he is coerced by peers to delete it.

(this post relates to *answers*, but the same logic applies to questions too)

Here's the thing; sometimes we are all capable of posting an answer that is **simply wrong**; incorrect, unhelpful, or actively harmful (in the context of the question) - maybe the answerer simply misread the question (*it happens*). It is *reasonable* to downvote such (ideally with a comment), and *upon realising the error*, it is reasonable to delete it. *This* is the scenario that badge is meant to address - your response to the realisation of an error.

There is also the position of having a view that you genuinely believe is correct and valid, but which is not popular; in that case feel free to not delete it. That's fine too.